# Showing non-https iframe in subdomain of https site

Tags: https

Now, I know that https site cannot show non-https 3rd party site in an iframe.

But if I get SSL cert for www.mydomain.com and mydomain.com ONLY, can subdomain.mydomain.com show non-https iframe content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If subdomain.mydomain.com is non-https, it can show non-https iframe content.

The only effect of the https on the parent domain (mydomain.com) is if the parent domain use HSTS (a header that tells the browser to force https) with the option includesubdomains: If that option is activated on the parent domain, then a visitor could be forced to visit subdomain.mydomain.com with https (even if you didn't activate https on it!)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sounds good. So I just have to make sure that the parent domain doesn't use HSTS. Is HSTS something I add to my php file or it is added by the SSL Cert vendor? If it is added by the vendor, do you know if I can request not to have it added?

Comment: You CAN use HSTS on the parent domain (and you should, it's a powerful security feature), just make sure to not use the includeSubdomains option. HSTS is an HTTP header (Strict-Transport-Security) so it can be set in your PHP or your apache/nginx/* config. It's not part of your certificate.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the clarification.